# AngularJs - pass in two selected id

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to pass in a selected award and selected judge into a controller

```
vm.assignJudge = function (array, index, judge, award) {
    judgeService
        .assignJudgeToAward(vm.judges,{ awardId: award.id, userId: judge.id })
        .success(function (e) {
            toastr.success("Judge assigned!", "Success!");          
            vm.selectedAward = {};
            vm.selectedJudge = {};
        });
};
```

Here is the html for the view

```
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" ng-repeat="judge in vm.judges track by judge.id">
        <td>
            <div class="md-checkbox checkbox-inline">
                <input name="judge{{judge.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="judge.isSelected" id="judge{{judge.id}}" ng-if="judge" class="md-checkbox" ng-change="vm.selectJudge($index,judge,vm.judges)">
                <label for="judge{{judge.id}}">
                    <span class="inc"></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
                {{judge.id}}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
                {{judge.name}}
            </a>
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-check" ng-if="judge.isInvitationAccepted"></i>
        </td>        
        <td ng-repeat="award in vm.awards track by award.id">
            <div class="md-checkbox checkbox-inline">
                <input name="award{{award.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="award.isSelected" id="award{{award.id}}" ng-if="award" class="md-checkbox" ng-change="vm.selectAward($index,award,vm.awards)">
                <label for="award{{award.id}}">
                    <span class="inc"></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            {{award.name}}
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am using module zero and here is the method code

```
public void AssignJudgeToAward(AssignJudgeToAwardInput input)
{
    UserAward assignJudgeToAward = _userAwardRepository.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == input.UserId);

    assignJudgeToAward.Award.Id = input.AwardId;
    assignJudgeToAward.User.Id = input.UserId;

    _userAwardRepository.InsertOrUpdate(assignJudgeToAward);

    _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

This is the code that calls the method in the controller.

```
<a ng-really-click="vm.assignJudge(judgeGroup.judgeItems, awardGroup.awardItems, $index, vm.selectedAward, vm.selectedJudge)" ng-class="{'disabled': !vm.selectedJudge.id}">
    <i></i> Assign Judge
</a>
```

Here is the assign judge to award function

```
vm.assignSelectJudgeToAward = function (position, judge, judges, award, awards) {
    angular.forEach(judges, awards, function (currentJudge, currentAward, index) {
        if (position !== index) {
            currentJudge.isSelected = false;
            currentAward.isSelected = false;
        } else {
            if (currentJudge.id && vm.selectedJudge.id === currentJudge.id && currentAward.id && vm.selectedAward.id === currentAward.id) {
                vm.selectedJudge = {};
                vm.selectedAward = {};
            } else {
                vm.selectedJudge = currentJudge;
                vm.selectedAward = currentAward;
                currentJudge.isSelected = true;
                currentAward.isSelected = true;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I am not getting an error at the minute, i am not getting anything.

The goal of this code is to insert a new record into a composite table called UserAward.

Comment: What error are you getting, and what does the judgeService.assignJudgeToAward function look like?

Comment: Are you applying `ng-controller` like this `ng-controller="SomeCtrl as vm"`?

Comment: the controller is attached to the first div in the view.

Comment: the assignJudgeToAward function has been added

Comment: You have an extra `<td>` in your view (just above the final `</td>`) - try removing that for a start. It would help if you posted the entire view so we can see where your view model is being applied.

Comment: controller is attached at top of view. View is way to big to fit in screen